# ng test with Jest fails with objValue.concat on an npm package

Tags: angular, jestjs, lodash

When I run `ng test` (using Jest) I get this error:

`An unhandled exception occurred: objValue.concat is not a function`

Checking the log file:

```
[error] TypeError: objValue.concat is not a function
    at concatArrayProperties (D:\...node_modules\@angular-builders\jest\dist\jest-configuration-builder.js:22:21)
    at baseMergeDeep (D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3643:11)
    at D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3603:11
    at D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4905:15
    at baseMerge (D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3600:7)
    at baseMergeDeep (D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3689:9)
    at D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3603:11
    at D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4905:15
    at baseMerge (D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3600:7)
    at baseMergeDeep (D:\...\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3689:9)
```

note: `...` was used to hide sensitive info

I can't figure out why this suddenly started happening or at least how to get jest to ignore lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Checks your "jest-preset-angular" version, on package.json

Comment: It's set to the latest stable release (8.3.1). I tried it at the next (9.0.0-next.0) but that didn't help either.

Comment: I had same problem when use "jest-preset-angular": "^8.2.1"
When I changed to "jest-preset-angular": "8.2.1" , without ^ it solved the problem.